# Element found but it's not clicked and the test fails

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm creating an automated test using amazon's website and I have to navigate to the "sign up" page.  The link to register an account is in a menu that only pops up when you hover over the sign in link.  When I type the following in the terminal I get the result I need

```
$$("a.nav-a[href*='https://www.amazon.com/ap/register']")
```

So I added it a `find_element()` method like this

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.nav-a[href*='https://www.amazon.com/ap/register']").click()
```

The page loads, which I have set to open in incognito mode, I can see the frame appear as it does when you hover over it, but it doesn't navigate to the page and I get an error pointing at this line of code.

I've also tried these

```
# searching from parent to child
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#nav-ya-flyout-ya-newCust a[href*="https://www.amazon.com/ap/register"]').click()

# searching by the text it contains
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.nav-a[contains(text(), 'Start here.')]").click()
```

Both of these yield the same result, selenium seems to find it but doesn't click it.  Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Where are you clicking the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, I needed to use the `ActionChains()` method and set it up like this

```
# Mouse Actions
mouse_actions = ActionChains(driver)

# Find Sign In link to hover over
signin = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#nav-link-accountList")

# Hover over sign in link
mouse_actions.move_to_element(signin).perform()

# Click Registration link
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.nav-a[href*="https://www.amazon.com/ap/register"]').click()
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with answering you own question. You can even mark this as the answer by clicking the check mark button.